# How to use environment profile with ehcache for mybatis?

Tags: ehcache, ehcache-3

We can config ehcache in classpath:ehcache.xml

But I have different environment profile such as "test","prod"

How can I use profile to config ehcache in different environment for mybatis?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot on the technologies you are using. So we can't give a precise answer right now.

If you only have test and prod, you will in general have on `ehcache.xml` in your production classpath and the another one shadowing it in your test classpath.

Then, if you have a more complicated use case, you need to have a way to load the different files. For Spring, for instance, you will use profiles. And lot `ehcache-prod.xml` and `ehcache-test.xml` according to it.